# Paypal Adaptive Payments paypal returns an empty post array

Tags: php, paypal

paypal response is returning an empty array what i am doing wrong?this is the data that i have sent in paypal and it came back a response that as empty post im using json to send data. sorry for the bad english.

```
<?php 
$apiUrl = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/";
$paypalUrl = "https://sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=";
$headers = array(
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".API_USER,
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".API_PASS,
                    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".API_SIG,
                    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
                    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
                    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".APP_ID
                    );
$envelope = array(
                    "errorLanguage" => "en_US",
                    "detailLevel" => "ReturnAll"
                    );              

    $create = array(
                    "actionType" => "PAY",
                    "currencyCode" => "USD",
                    "receiverList" => array(
                        "receiver" => array(
                            array(
                                "amount" => "2.00",
                                "email" => "1@gmail.com"
                            ),
                            array(
                                "amount" => "5.00",
                                "email" => "2@gmail.com"
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                     "returnUrl" => "domain.php",
                    "cancelUrl" => "domain.php",
                    "ipnNotificationUrl" => "ipn.php",
                    "requestEnvelope" => $envelope
                );
                $response = paypalSend($createPacket,"Pay");
                $payKey = $response['payKey'];

    $details = array(
                "requestEnvelope" => $envelope,
                "payKey" => $payKey,
                "receiverOptions" => array(
                    array(
                            "receiver" => array("email" => "1@gmail.com"),
                            "invoiceData" => array(
                                "item" => array(
                                    array(
                                            "name" => "product 1",
                                            "price" => "1.00",
                                            "identifier" => "p1"
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            "name" => "product 1",
                                            "price" => "1.00",
                                            "identifier" => "p1"
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                    ),
                    array(
                            "receiver" => array("email" => "2@gmail.com"),
                            "invoiceData" => array(
                                "item" => array(
                                    array(
                                            "name" => "product 1",
                                            "price" => "2.00",
                                            "identifier" => "p1"
                                        ),
                                    array(
                                            "name" => "product 1",
                                            "price" => "3.00",
                                            "identifier" => "p1"
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                    ),
                )
    );

            $res = paypalSend($details, "PaymentDetails");
     ?>


    <?php           
    function paypalSend($data,$call) {

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl.$call);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            return json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a bunch of stuff that doesn't belong in the PaymentDetails request.  There are only 3 parameters in that request:  PayKey, TransactionID, and TrackingID.

You've got all this stuff with receiverOptions going on.  I think you're just making the PayPal server confused.

Get rid of everything in that $details value except for the payKey and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for replying this is what i use                   `$headers = array(
"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: ".API_USER,
     "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: ".API_PASS,
     "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: ".API_SIG,
     "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
     "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON",
     "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: ".APP_ID
     );`

Comment: how can i get the paypal response??i use this to store the response         `file_put_contents('export.txt', var_export($_POST, true));` but its empty array.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the correct endpoint?  Are you sure CURL is enabled on your server?  It would help to see the full script. Are you using an SDK in particular?

Comment: i already edited the code above and its running my problem is i dont get any response from paypal i only get empyt post array.

Comment: my curl is enabled i can receive my paykey my problem is i dont get the paypal response it only return an empty post. i dont use sdk.

Comment: So how are you getting the PayKey if you're not getting a response?  Seems like maybe your log is just clearing out the value or not saving like you're expecting..??  What if you just dump the response out on screen immediately?  You gotta be getting something if you're getting the PayKey back.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You're saying the Pay call is working, but then PayDetails is coming back blank.  Let me see if I can reproduce that.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me:  http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/PaymentDetails.php  I updated the answer with something I noticed.

Comment: thank you for your reply.is this the response from paypal IPN that you prodived after you pay the items??this is where im having problems. cause the response return to me an empty post array after i paid the product it returns empty. @Andrew

Comment: No, IPN is something entirely different.  That is just the result of the PaymentDetails API request.  Again, yours has a bunch of stuff in it that isn't compatible with that request.

Comment: Can you tell me on how to get that request in ipn. i already get the paymentdetails thats the only problem im facing right now im only receving an empty post array. . . .

Comment: You don't seem to be paying any attention to what I'm saying, but IPN docs can be found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).